# Highlight lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea that is for checking valid telephone numbers. I want to highlight the lines that contain invalid telephone numbers. I have logic to put two starts in front of the invalid numbers.

I have no idea how to highlight the whole line (row) in textarea.

What I did is:

```
var tarea = $("textarea[id='myId']");
var lines = tarea.val().split('\n');
tarea.val(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].startsWith("**")) {
        var tempText = '<mark style="background-color:red;">' + lines[i] + '</mark>';
        tarea.append(tempText);
        tarea.append('\n');
    } else {
        tarea.append(lines[i]);
        tarea.append('\n');
    }
}
```

The code above highlights only the strings, not the full line. Please help me to modify the codes to highlight the line.

[image: what I have implemented]

---------------------Edit----------------------------

The above solution works for IE only. Can anyone help to make it work in Chrome and FF?

In Chrome and FF, the textarea is empty after doing above. I've checked that tarea.val() is " ", and tarea.html() is with the  tags and all text. But it's not showing in textarea.

Comment: Set `width` of `mark` to `width` of `textarea` ?

Comment: you can't color the text in a textarea without coloring ALL the text. the closest thing you can do is select one of the bad parts.

Comment: @guest271314 Just tried. It's not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pre` element with `contentEditable` set to `true` , set `mark` element `display` to `block`

```css
pre {
  font-family:sans;
  width:400px;
}

mark {
  background:red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<pre contentEditable="true">
+1234567890
<mark>abcdefghij</mark>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks first. It did extend the highlight parts. But the length of the highlighting part differs. And it also added a black line in my textarea.

Comment: Will input of each line be limited to maximum of twelve characters ?

Comment: unfortunately, no. Telephone numbers in different countries could result in different length.

Comment: @Payson See updated post. Adjusted `mark` `display` to `block`

Comment: thanks a lot. However. I can't make it work in other browsers. So I changed from textarea to contenteditable div.